# How different are EF 4.0 and EF 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework

I guess that EF4.1 is recent to EF4.0, but I didn't find any book on EF4.1, but 2 books on EF4.0.

can I still buy the book on EF4.0 expecting that I will get most of the concept??

Thanks for helping.

Comment: EF 4.1 doesn't bring any new features it just brings second API and new mapping technique so everything from EF 4.0 is still valid and unless you want to use second (simplified but in many ways worse/less powerful) API or code-first mapping you can use EF 4.0 directly and you will have the last version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The ADO.NET Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/04/11/ef-4-1-released.aspx), there are two main features:

> - The DbContext API is a simplified abstraction over ObjectContext and a number of other types that were included in previous releases of the ADO.NET Entity Framework. The DbContext API surface is optimized for common tasks and coding patterns. DbContext can be used with Database First, Model First and Code First development.
> - Code First is a new development pattern for the ADO.NET Entity Framework and provides an alternative to the existing Database First and Model First patterns. Code First is focused around defining your model using C#/VB.NET classes, these classes can then be mapped to an existing database or be used to generate a database schema. Additional configuration can be supplied using Data Annotations or via a fluent API.

EF 4.0 books are good unless you are using one of those 2 features, because you won't find them in there.

But you have plenty of resources online about those new features (especially Code First).

You even have official tutorials:

- [Using DbContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx)
- [Code First walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)